# Select outer parent frame from child in css

Tags: css

Good day all,

I have an a tag with class "WORKSHEET_block" and which is contained in 3 other div.

The css to style is (which does not work):

```css
.WORKSHEET_block < .fc-daygrid-event-harness < .fc-daygrid-day-events < .fc-daygrid-day-frame {
  background-color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame">
  <div class="fc-daygrid-day-events">
    <div class="fc-daygrid-event-harness">
      <a class="WORKSHEET_block">My Value</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I know if it was the other way around from parent to child we would use ">" from the parent to the child.

Is there anywhere I can select the parent from the child?

Comment: Can't you invert the selector to look like this? `.fc-daygrid-day-frame > .fc-daygrid-day-events > .fc-daygrid-event-harness > .WORKSHEET_block`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.fc-daygrid-day-frame:has(.WORKSHEET_block) {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame">
  <div class="fc-daygrid-day-events">
    <div class="fc-daygrid-event-harness">
      <a class="WORKSHEET_block">This is the child using the class</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame">
  <div class="fc-daygrid-day-events">
    <div class="fc-daygrid-event-harness">
      <a>this child does not have any class</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using :has relative selector. I have inserted an extra HTML code it doesn't have a `WORKSHEET_block` class, so the style is not applying to it